Nginx Configuration: Redirect Specific Path and Preserve URL
I'm configuring Nginx to handle redirects for a domain, but I'm encountering an issue with preserving the URL for a specific path. Here's my scenario:
I have a domain, let's say landing.immancrze.us, and I want all requests to this domain to be redirected to app.immancrze.us, except for requests to the path landing.immancrze.us/potential-ownership. For the latter, I want to serve the content without redirection and ensure that the URL remains unchanged.
for example:

Requests to landing.immancrze.us will be redirected to app.immancrze.us.

Requests to landing.immancrze.us/potential-ownership will be served directly without redirection and the URL in the browser will remain unchanged like http://landing.immancrze.us/potential-ownership.
but it will getting changed to http://app.immancrze.us/potential-ownership


Here's the Nginx configuration I've tried:
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name landing.immancrze.us;

    # Redirect root path to app.immancrze.us
    location = / {
        return 301 http://app.immancrze.us$request_uri;
    }

    # Serve content for /potential-ownership without redirection
    location = /potential-ownership {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html/;
        index index.html;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    # Serve JavaScript files with custom headers
    location ~ \.js$ {
        sendfile off;
        add_header Last-Modified $date_gmt;
        add_header Cache-Control 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate, max-age=0';
        if_modified_since off;
        expires off;
        etag off;
        #proxy_no_cache 1;
        #proxy_cache_bypass 1;
    }

    # Handle all other requests by redirecting to app.complycta.us
    location / {
        return 301 http://app.immancrze.us$request_uri;
    }
}


Is /usr/share/nginx/html/potential-ownership a directory containing index.html?

no  index.html contained in this  /usr/share/nginx/html

To serve index.html from /usr/share/nginx/html/ you need to use try_files /index.html =404;

If index.html also requires resource files (JS, CSS, JPEG) you may have a problem. You will need to identify the URLs for those resource files and add exceptions for those too.

yes getting ERR_ABORTED 404 for  resource files (JS, CSS, JPEG)

any other way i can do it

location = / and location = /potential-ownership places in one level and nginx terminates right after the first comparison. location = /  cannot obviously contain nested locations
Try to move your block
 # Redirect root path to app.immancrze.us
    location = / {
        return 301 http://app.immancrze.us$request_uri;
    }

after this block
# Serve content for /potential-ownership without redirection
    location = /potential-ownership {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html/;
        index index.html;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

and try don't use = for location /potential-ownership (expl. location /potential-ownership, location /)
